# Why there is mutiple roots error in my XML?

Tags: xml, spring

I am trying to learn Spring by following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7c6ZTF6cF88&index=4&list=PLC97BDEFDCDD169D7). I created a spring.xml file at root of src folder using IntelliJ. But I got the following error:

[image]

What is wrong of my XML? How to fix it? Thanks!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE properties SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd">



<properties/>


<beans>
    <bean id="triangle">

    </bean>

</beans>
```

I still got error after I change the xml file to the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd">


<beans>
    <bean id="triangle">

    </bean>

</beans>
```

After I changed my code to the following, xml is correct, but I got java compiler error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/beans.dtd">


<beans>
    <bean id="triangle">

    </bean>

</beans>
```

The error message is: 
Line 2 in XML document from file [/Users/nick/testProj/gs-rest-service/initial/src/main/spring.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2;

I still got Java compiler error after I change xml to the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- A simple bean definition -->
    <bean id="triangle" class="no class">
        <!-- collaborators and configuration for this bean go here -->
    </bean>


    <!-- more bean definitions go here -->

</beans>
```

Answer (score 4):

A well-formed XML document has exactly one "root element" that directly or indirectly contains all other elements.  Your XML has two elements that neither one contains the other: one `<properties>` element and one `<beans>` element.  That the former is empty is irrelevant.

If you're trying to write XML for a Spring `webmvc-context.xml`, then the root element should be `<beans>`.

I'm not sure what the `<properties/>` element is supposed to be doing, and the `DOCTYPE` declaration is pretty suspicious.  I would have expected the root element to reference the appropriate schema instead of the document containing a DOCTYPE declaration, and if a DOCTYPE were referenced then the one given seems unlikely to be correct.

Comment: I updated my code based on your suggestion, but still got error. Can you please copy & paste me a correct example of bean definition xml? This is so strange to me~

Comment: What is the official correct way to define a bean? The one showed in tutorial video doesn't work. Strange~~~~

Comment: @NicolasS.Xu, there are numerous examples available from Google.  I strongly suggest that you prefer those presented in text form, as opposed to videos.  Ultimately, the Spring reference documentation is the authority, but I suspect that's a little too heavy for you.  A complete example is a little large for an answer, especially since Spring uses multiple XML files, and I'm uncertain which one you're actually trying to write.

Comment: @NicolasS.Xu, but **do** take out the DOCTYPE delcaration, and also the `standalone="no"`.

Comment: I guess there is too much gap in my knowledge to figure out the problem. Do you know where is best place to look up xml bean definition? I tried https://docs.spring.io/ , but couldn't find it.

Comment: @NicolasS.Xu, yes, docs.spring.io seems to be down at the moment.  I hope and presume that's temporary.  Other than that, I cannot refer you to a *best* online example, but there is a fairly *recent* one here: http://crunchify.com/spring-mvc-how-to-declare-a-bean-in-spring-application/. Some of the details may not apply to you, but there is a `<beans>` XML descriptor there.

Comment: Thank you so much!